# Which abilities can be cancelled by Lulu's Polymorph?

Tags: league-of-legends

Lulu's Polymorph changes the enemy into a squirrel for a few seconds, slowing them down, and also preventing them from attacking and using abilities.

[image: example of polymorph]

It seems to cancel some abilities, like Death Lotus from Katarina, or Warwick's ultimate.

However, there are a lot of other abilities which are not cancelled, and keep going even during the polymorph. This leads to strange effects, like for example a squirrel running after you with a circle of fire around him (Mundo) or a sword spinning (Garen). It also doesn't cancel Fiddlestick's ultimate, once he teleported.

You would expect someone changed as a squirrel to be unable to do such things. So what exactly can and can't be cancelled by Lulu's Polymorph?

Comment: It is basicly an overpowered silence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a moment to [look at this article](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Types_of_Crowd_Control)... It shows you what Polymorph can interrupt:

> - ​The target is unable to attack or cast abilities and is slowed for    the duration.
>
>   - This is distinct from Blind as the target cannot attack    at all: as such, on-hit effects are never used/wasted.
>   - Whimsy also    transforms the target into a small critter (reducing their size).
> - **Interrupts the [channeling](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Channel) of abilities.**
> - The duration is affected by crowd control reduction.
> - The effect can be removed by all cleansing effects.

---

Abilities that have already been activated can not be interrupted.

[Garen's Spinning blade](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Garen/Ability_Details) is no channeling effect. It's a one time cast that appears for a few seconds. This can not be interrupted by Lulu's Polymorph.

> (Active): Garen rapidly spins his sword around his body for 3 seconds,
>   dealing physical damage to nearby enemies every half second. Minions
>   and neutral monsters take 75% damage from this ability. Garen can
>   deactivate Judgment early by activating the ability again after 0.5
>   seconds. Garen ignores unit collision, but his movement speed is
>   slowed by 20% if spinning through minions. Judgment's damage can
>   critically strike, in which case, only the bonus damage will be
>   multiplied.
>   - No cost
>   - Diameter of AoE: 330

Note though that casting Polymorph on a spinning Garen will prevent him from deactivating the ability early.

Comment: Ah, I see. The key mechanic is "Channeling": http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Channel. All those abilities can be stopped. Garen's Judgement doesn't seem to be considered a channeling ability.

Comment: @Gnoupi Ah yes! Garens spin is a one time activated spell and then he spins for a few seconds... and its not channeling

Comment: @Gnoupi Editted the answer for garen's spell.

Answer (score 0):

Lux's ultimate also can't be interrupted with any cc. And I'm not sure about Ezreal's ultimate.

Comment: Indeed, according to [this](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Channel), they can be interrupted by death, though

Comment: I have been fried by a squirrel several times, from what I can recall.

Comment: Well for me death isn't a cc, it's more like... death.